# Highcharts. Mark some points

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, highcharts

It is posible mark some point with a symbol? I do not want mark a serie, I want to mark some points of a serie in highchart graphic.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,
You can set the marker to be on only for certain points. See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/5jjJG/) example.

```
series: [{
            data: [{
                y: 29.9,
                marker: {
                    enabled: true,
                    radius: 5,
                    symbol: 'diamond'
                }
            },
            71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]
```

Comment: The fiddle url doesnt exist anymore.

Comment: @pbwned - True but the code sample here is still functional.